# Select all entities which do not have children -- getting a lot of rows back, is this correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 84,000 rows in my Users table. Users are created automatically. So, I thought it would be nice to see how many users actually did anything after being created. I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users u
JOIN Folders f ON UserId = u.Id
JOIN Playlists p ON FolderId = f.Id
WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PlaylistItems WHERE PlaylistId = p.Id)
```

My intent is to only count users which have no playlist items in any of their playlists. This query returned 74,000 results which seems high.

I'm wondering if this query is selecting all users which have at least one playlist with no items in it. That is, if a user has two playlists -- one empty and one populated -- are they still counted in my query? And, if so, how can I modify it to select only users which have only empty playlists.

If that's vastly more difficult then I might try my hand at counting only users with 1 playlist which is empty.

The database structure is:

- Many users. 1:1 user:folder, 1:many folder:playlists, 1:many playlists:playlistItems

Comment: What database are you on here?

Comment: what are you trying to do ? I cannot imagine what your database is like.

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT u.Id)`

Comment: Distinct drops it down to 69k from 74k! @blasto Just trying to delete unused accounts. I added the 1-many relationship structure into my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better pattern than counting every single playlist and comparing is simply finding all the users who don't have anything in any playlist. I like `NOT EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT COUNT(u.Id)
  FROM dbo.Users AS u
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PlayLists AS pl
     INNER JOIN dbo.PlayListItems AS pli
     ON pl.id = pli.PlayListID
     INNER JOIN dbo.Folders AS f
     ON p.FolderID = f.ID
     WHERE f.UserID = u.Id
  );
```

As an aside, calling a column `Id` in its primary table and something else everywhere else might seem like a good idea, but I find it quite confusing. Why isn't a FolderID called a FolderID everywhere in the data model?

Comment: As far as I am aware I've named everything appropriately. It's ID on the Folder table and FolderID when referenced by a User or a Playlist. Anyway, this is what I wanted, thank you! :)

Comment: Well, appropriate is relative. I prefer a CustomerID to be called a CustomerID everywhere in the model.

Comment: I suppose. I find it a bit repetitive. I'm not going to say "Customer.CustomerName" when it has a name. I'd just say "Customer.Name", similiarly I say "Customer.ID" but I suppose that's just inherited from the structure of code I work in.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that for CustomerName, because you don't repeat CustomerName in other tables in the model, so there is no need to disambiguate. You also wouldn't say Customer.CustomerID either because, ideally, you would use shorter aliases to make your code more readable. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Break down your query:

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) FROM Users u
JOIN Folders f ON UserId = u.Id
JOIN Playlists p ON FolderId = f.Id
join  PlaylistItems on PlaylistId = p.Id
group by u.id
```

This should provide you with a list of all users and the count of the number of rows in playlists by userID.  a couple ways to go...

Take a count of all users not in that list:

```
select count(*) from users where id not in (SELECT u.id FROM Users u
JOIN Folders f ON UserId = u.Id
JOIN Playlists p ON FolderId = f.Id
join  PlaylistItems on PlaylistId = p.Id
group by u.id)
```

MySQL performs poorly on that...same thing using left join:

```
 select count(*) 
from   users u left join  (SELECT u.id, COUNT(*) FROM Users u
JOIN Folders f ON UserId = u.Id
JOIN Playlists p ON FolderId = f.Id
join  PlaylistItems on PlaylistId = p.Id
group by u.id)a 
on a.id = u.id
where a.id is null
```

Comment: Question is tagged SQL Server; MySQL is not involved.

Comment: awww, it got editted in...I was feeling clever for that